# How to make a filter chain thread-local?

Tags: java, multithreading, filter

I'm trying to implement a filter chain, which is literally the same for each incoming message. Is there any idea how this code can be improved, so that to avoid creating a `FilterChain` object for each message. Does making a filter chain as `ThreadLocal` (and then asking each thread to return a copy of it) buy me anything in this situation?

```java
// a common interface for all filters that might be added to a filter chain
public interface Filter {
    void doFilter(Message message, FilterChain chain);
}
```

```java
// a filter chain implementation
class FilterChain {
    private final Iterator<Filter> filtersIterator;

    FilterChain(List<Filter> filters) {
        filtersIterator = filters.iterator();
    }

    void doFilter(Message message) {
        if (filtersIterator.hasNext())
            filtersIterator.next().doFilter(message, this);
    }
}
```

```java
// an abstract bot class
public abstract class AbstractBot {
    private final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    private final List<Filter> filters = addFilters();

    // handles message objects
    protected abstract void process(Message message);

    // an overridable hook for subclasses to add their own list of filters
    protected List<Filter> addFilters() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void start() {
        // just before we start, add the last-in-chain filter implemented by lambda,
        // whose only purpose is to hand over a message object to the process-method
        filters.add((message, chain) -> process(message));

        while (true) {
            // make long-polling requests to the server for incoming messages
            List<Message> messages = requestMessages();
            for (Message message : messages) {
                executor.execute(() -> {
                    FilterChain chain = new FilterChain(filters);
                    chain.doFilter(message);
                });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just move `FilterChain chain = new FilterChain(filters);` out of the `while` loop?

Comment: @Kayaman If I do so, executor's threads will be contending for a common FilterChain's iterator, which would cause havoc.

Comment: @Kayaman Imagine, one thread calls `chain.doFilter(message)` which moves `FilterChain` iterator to the next filter position, then comes another thread and calls `chain.doFilter(message)`, which uses very same `FilterChain` iterator, but this iterator has already moved to the next filter, so the second thread won't have the chance to use the first filter in a chain and so on...

Comment: You need to create an iterator for each message anyway. Now you're creating your `FilterChain` object *and* the iterator in it. So `ThreadLocal` will not help, but removing the unnecessary `FilterChain` class will. You could just iterate the list inside the lambda.

Comment: Since currently your `FilterChain` class isn't reusable anyway. So instead of redesigning the class to make it work with `ThreadLocal`, and restart the internal iterator for each message, you could just stick a for loop in the lambda and get the simplest solution with the least objects created. But if you don't like simple and effective, you're free to involve all the `ThreadLocals` you want.

Comment: I could declare a `ThreadLocal<FilterChain> chain` variable and then just use `chain.get()` inside lambda, but I'm not sure how much I can gain from this approach... so far, I agree with you that iterating over filter's list directly inside lambda would be the simplest solution.

Comment: ThreadLocal's are very rarely a *good* solution, they can be handy in some cases when working with existing code. If possible (and it often is when you're not working with an existing codebase), it's better to aim for thread-safe solution from the start instead.

Comment: The purpose of the entire code is unclear. 1) What is the purpose of the `Filter`? It doesn’t return a result, so it’s actual purpose must contradict the name “filter”. 2) Why does each `Filter` get the `FilterChain` as argument when it can’t do anything useful with it? 3) Why does `FilterChain` exist at all when it is only a wrapper around a trivial loop? The relevant object is the `List<Filter>` which has been constructed in the `addFilters()` call already. Just use something like `for(Message message: messages) executor.execute(() -> { for(Filter f: filters) f.doFilter(message); });`